# CS - Switch jobs, maintain $$

Tags: computer-science

I currently work as a senior engineer building workflows at a FAANG (Backend Python mostly, but I do know my way around Angular). I'm planning on switching jobs either to a Software Development Manager(14+ years in the industry) or take an engineer position working with ML/DL because I don't find what I'm doing fulfilling anymore. But I'm having hard time doing it.

I want to try out one of two things:

1. Apply for Engineering Manager openings:

- I see a lot of "specific" job openings for Engineering Managers with experience in a LOT of technologies besides Python. (CI/CD, DEVOps experience etc.,).
- When I apply for EM position at FAANGs that are remotely matching, what and how do I prep? Leetcode? System Design Primer? Build some side projects?!

2. Follow my passion and specialize in ML/DL:

   This has been my passion for about 4+ years now, but I keep failing because I don't work with ML/DL everyday. I cannot find projects, open source or otherwise that I can contribute to everyday and so I lose all the information I learnt very soon, I also don't have Math/STAT background.

   I tried to go to college to get an "online" degree to get up to speed on Math/Stat, but I didn't pursue it since I'm not really sure if I'll be hired as a Sr. Engineer and will be able to maintain the $$ AFTER completing the degree without experience(have a family + 2 kids, spouse not working).

Did anyone here kept polishing your "other" skills outside of your day job consistently and land a Sr. Engineer position in that area/technology? What/How do you choose your side projects/ Github Repos to contribute?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can teach yourself math and statistics.  All you need is a used textbook and a couple of hours a week.  Save your money. All a degree will get you is an empty wallet, sleepless nights studying for an exam, and to do the same exact practice problems from that book I mentioned earlier

Comment: Suppose you get a college degree in ML/DL in the next few years. Then, you apply for a new ML/DL job. Should companies hire and pay you the salary of an entry level ML/DL developer ? Or should they hire and pay you the salary of a senior/principal ML/DL developer even though you have no industry working experience with ML/DL ?

Comment: The math and statistics used in ML is NOT coded by you. You plop in algorithms and analyze the output to see if it makes sense, and try different types of ML/NN techniques and methods for grouping results to check your conclusions, then develop strategies to confirm validity with real-world data. You do NOT go in and calculate those algorithms by hand because it'll take you forever. You also typically don't code your own algorithms for the same reason you do not code your own encryption (but the consequence is less severe).

Comment: If you are at a FAANG why are you not asking the managers there what was required to get their jobs instead of Internet strangers?

Answer (score 8):

So I really suggest you pick one path or the other first.  Splitting your efforts is going to make things harder.

If you're applying for manager roles and currently a dev-  why would you prep by writing code?  Managers don't code, or code very little.  A mid level or even decent junior has the coding skills a manager needs.  A manager's job is dealing with people, coordinating, motivating, dealing with politics, working with budgets, hiring, etc.  Coding is the absolute lowest priority, and most never do it outside of a hack week.  You should be working on your people skills and conflict resolution skills, not technical skills.

As for switching specialties-  I've done that a half dozen times in my career.  Especially at bigger companies they tend to hire on potential and intelligence rather than exact skill match.  So long as you do know the basics of ML, just apply.  The problem I see with your statement is twofold.  First, you say you keep forgetting things.  I get that, I forget ML every time I put it down too.  But if you want to get a job in it, you need to keep the basics in memory.  Go back to your college days (or high school, whatever) and study.  There's no replacement for that.

The other problem is you say there's no open source projects you can join.  First, that's dubious.  A quick google search comes up with dozens just in Python.  But even if that's true-  start one.  Try and do some facial recognition.  Or voiceprint matching.  Or fingerprints.  Or some sentiment analysis.  It doesn't need to be world class, it needs to be yours.  It will serve both to keep you in practice and as a portfolio.

Comment: Incorporate basic ML in your current job. Do comment grab of an entire project and do data analysis on it, then see if you can figure out some kind of pattern to, say, deployment success compared to day of week (e.g. do deployments fail more on Friday?).

Comment: Why do ML projects so often sound like a dictatorship crushing its citizens? *"If you want a picture of the future, imagine a boot stamping on a human face— forever"*

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find taking graduate level courses very helpful. Not those online extension classes, but actually getting permission to take a Machine Learning course at a university, like Stanford or Berkeley for credit if you can. Do get some math background if you want to seriously progress as an ML Engineer (start with linear alegra--matrix transformations are not difficult). The reason is that graduate courses are very tough and will force you to assimilate difficult new information in a short amount of time and you will produce a fairly complex and elaborate project at the end. Even now I have still retained a lot from a data science course that I took 2 years ago in spite of not working with NLP and ML everyday. YMMV but the sheer difficulty of earning an A in grad courses will drill the subject matter deep into your head. Upload your homework and final projects to Github and review them on a weekly basis (be able to walk your interviewer through how you built the final project). You can also look for some ML projects/libraries on Github and help improve them. It's considered open-source too especially if it will eventually be usable by professionals in an industry. You don't have to only choose famous open source projects. With all this you should be ready for ML Engineer interviews.